# View PDF document in ios using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am not able to get perfect solution for view pdf document in apple phone. I am using cordova/jquerymobile, able to download document using cordova plugin file and file-transfer. I tried fileOpener plugin but its not work properly, using object and iframe tag get issue in scroll and fit.

==I am looking here how to disaply pdf document from remote or locally downloaded, Here my pdf download code for ref ==

```
    function DownloadFile(docid_page) {
var myFile = decodeURIComponent(docid_page.replace(/\+/g, " ")); //str.replace(/%20/g, " ");
  var remoteFile = myFile.replace(/\s/g, "%20");
  var localFileName ="Portico/" + remoteFile.substring(remoteFile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  //alert(localFileName);
  var statusDom;
  statusDom = document.querySelector('#status');
  //----creating directory for documents--------
     window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onFileSystemFail);

      function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
          console.log(fileSystem.name);
          var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
          directoryEntry.getDirectory("Portico", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail)
      }
      function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
          console.log(parent);
      }
      function onDirectoryFail(error) {
          console.log("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
      }
      function onFileSystemFail(evt) {
          console.log(evt.target.error.code);
      }
  //------end here----------------
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(localFileName, {
      create: true,
      exclusive: false
    }, function(fileEntry) {
      var localPath = fileEntry.toURL();
      var ft = new FileTransfer();
      ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
          $('#status').show();
          var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded /
            progressEvent.total * 100);
          statusDom.innerHTML = "Downloading : " + perc + "%";
        } else {
          if (statusDom.innerHTML == "") {
            statusDom.innerHTML = "Loading";
          } else {
            statusDom.innerHTML += ".";
          }
        }
      };
      ft.download(remoteFile, localPath, function(entry) {
        // var dwnldImg = document.getElementById("dwnldImg");
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
        var disPath=decodeURIComponent(entry.fullPath);
        navigator.notification.alert('Successfully downloaded in \n' +disPath, null,'Portico', 'OK');
        //alert('Download successful! ' + entry.fullPath);
        $('#status').hide();
      }, fail);
    }, fail);
  }, fail);
}

function fail(error) {
     navigator.notification.alert('Could not download. Try again later', null,'Portico', 'OK');
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
  }
```

Comment: Guys anyone can help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [inAppBrowser plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser) with _blank option

```
window.open(pathToPDF, '_blank');
```

the pathToPDF can be an online url or a local url of a downloaded file

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Used already but issue with back to previous screen.. kill the application only the solution for ios

Comment: I don't understand what you say. Do you mean that you can't go back? A close button should appear on the in app browser

Comment: ok, not used inappbrowser plugin for window.open...anyway thank you again for ur efforts!

Answer (score 0):

ohh! After long time search i found the perfect solution for view pdf in ios.."ExternalFileUtil" I used plugin ***$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/critical/cordova-external-file-open.git***